# Object of a class as return type of method of another class

Tags: c++, class

Can someone give me a sample code where I have a class object which is the return type of the method of another class?I try doing it by simply mentioning the classname in front of the method but there occurs an error saying not a valid type...

```
typedef struct Point
{
   int x,y;

}Point;

class Node

{
public: 
    int posX;
    int posY;
    int width;
    int height;
    Node *child[4];         
        Point array[100];

}Node;



class quadtree
    {
        public:
        void setnode(Node *xy,int x,int y,int w,int h);
        Node buildtree(Node* n);
        void printtree(Node* n,int depth);      
        void deletetree(Node* n);
        Node *BuildNode(Node* n, Node  *nParent, int index);        
        static int pointArray_size(Node *n);
        //Node *rootNode ;      
        int randn();        
                quadtree();
        ~quadtree();

    friend class Node;    
    };
```

Above is the relevant piece not the entire code.I am trying to change Node which was originally a struct to class.And this i dont know how to do..

Comment: Did you forward declare the class or include the proper header?

Comment: Show us the code you have please.

Comment: @pinkpanther No special meaning except for that number :)

Comment: The `typedef class...` thing is useless in C++ and you have a global object `Node` with the same name as the class, which is never really a good thing.

Comment: sorry chris but I m new to C++ ....So how do i solve my problem..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Node
{...} Node;
```

Here you're creating an instance of `Node` named `Node`. Then inside your function prototypes/definitions you use `Node` as if it were a type, when its not. Maybe you meant to `typedef` the class:

```
typedef class Node {...} Node;
```

But you don't even need a `typedef` here in C++ because class names don't require a prefix of `class` or `struct`. Just use the class name:

```
class Name {...};
```

Comment: Oh rite...thanks a lot solved the problem...as you said I was tryin to typedef and making a mess of it...